# Matlab: `gfrank` over GF(2^m)

Tags: matlab

I've been working with matrices over GF(2) in Matlab.  Well, I've been working with 0/1 matrices that I've been treating as being defined over GF(2).  I was surprised/happy to see that Matlab provides some functionality in the Communications System Toolbox for working over finite fields.  In particular, if I want to find the rank of a matrix over a finite field, there are a couple of methods: (1) use `gfrank` on the matrices that I already have defined, or (2) use `rank` on a Galois field array (created with `gf`).  For matrices over GF(2), the former method seems to be significantly faster; however, there's a problem...

The [documentation for `gfrank`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/comm/ref/gfrank.html) says that the function doesn't work over fields of the form GF(2^m).  I double checked on a toy example, and specifying GF(2) as the field to work over seems to output correct results.  Moreover, the function's m-file specifies GF(2) as the default field (by specifying the second argument as `2` if `nargin < 2`).  Something *has* to be wrong here, and it seems to be the documentation.  However, I'd hate to assume that the documentation is wrong only to find out much later that the computation doesn't always work over GF(2^m).  Does anybody know for sure what's wrong here?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any updates on this? I've been experiencing dubious results using gfrank as well.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Sorry.